# Way to make this for loop with np.sums go faster

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code that iterates a list of matrixes, getting the np.sum of them and adding/subtracting over variables. 
This code is a part of a larger simulation problem I am tackling and since this little piece of code runs to about 10mi+ times every time I run the whole program, I am trying to make it the most efficient as possible. 
Is there any way to simplify this, making it run faster? I have looked for some vetorization tips but found none on how to make this more efficient

```py
#mi could be of any size
mi = np.random.randint(2,size=(4,4))
#the arrays in list_of_blocks could be of any size so the np.sum of the list would end in a ValueError
list_of_blocks = [np.array([[0],[1]]),np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0]])]
nee = np.sum(mi)
n1 =0
mrxnr= 0
for block in list_of_blocks:
    nee -= np.sum(block)
    n1 += np.sum(block)
    mrxnr += block.shape[0]*block.shape[1]
```

Comment: using a np.sum(list_of_blocks) wont work because the arrays inside of it could be of any size or shape, so if you try:
```python
list_of_blocks = [np.array([[0],[1]]),np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0]])]
```
the np.sum will return a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization works by applying some operation over numpy arrays, which have data stored in a contiguous chunk of memory. That is not the case for lists, so a loop seems Ok for this situation.

However there are a few things in your code that con be optimized.
Are the arrays in  `list_of_blocks` always `0` or `1`? If that is the case, `count_nonzero` is much faster than `sum`.

Also, `block.shape[0]*block.shape[1]` is equivalent to `block.size`, which is also faster.

Finally, `nee` and `n1` are related, so there is no need to compute `sum(block)` *twice* for each loop cycle. The optimized code:

```
nee = np.sum(mi)
n1 =0
mrxnr= 0
for block in list_of_blocks:
    n1 += np.count_nonzero(block)
    mrxnr += block.size
nee -=n1
```

Comment: Thank you for your aswer, the arrays in ```python list_of_blocks``` are indeed always 0 and 1, so this should work just fine. Tested in the context of the whole program and the speed time using a 7x7 matrix went from ```python 767ms``` to ```python 574ms```, so this improved the overall speed already.